# propertyBinding Controller - view

Tags: ember.js

So, I am trying to get a simple propertyBinding to work with emberjs. Specifically, I have a controller with a content property, that gets updated under certain circumstances and a view, which needs that content array to draw some chart.

I have made the most basic example and it doesn't seem to work. My simple example is the following:

```
Appname.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    value: 'bla'
});

Appname.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'Index',
    propertyBinding: 'Appname.IndexController.value',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('Indexview');
        console.log(this.get('property'));
    }
 });
```

It is as simple as that, and it just does not work. What is really odd though, if I create another testcontroller (rather then extending it) e.g.

```
Appname.TestController = Ember.Controller.create({
    value: 'jpopo'
});
```

the property binding works all of the sudden. But I just can not get it to work with the IndexController
(And in case the information is necessary, in the Applicaton.hbs I have an outlet)
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings work for instantiated objects, not for object definitions.

`Appname.IndexController` is the controller definition, not an instance. It is not what you want to bind to. The Ember.js app will create an instance of `IndexController`, and it's that created instance that you want to bind to:

To access the actual controller instance from its view, use `controller`.

```
Appname.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'index',
  propertyBinding: 'controller.value',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log(this.get('property'));
  }
});
```

Of course, that is if you follow [Ember.js conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/).

Comment: Sorry for not marking it yet as accepted answer. Just tried it real quick and it didn't work, but I haven't had time to look at it properly. Will do that soon though. In the meantime, thanks for already nudging me into the right direction.